# Pyspark java.lang.StackOverflowError while saving large dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am encountering the below error while trying to save the dataframe. I dont see a failure in any of the stages in spark history server but the code terminates with below errror message. The dataframe has a large size of 566171 rows and 1441 columns.

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1644.save.
: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I have also noticed that for dataframe with lesser number of columns the code works fine and dataframe is saved to hdfs.

Another interesting thing I noticed is for the dataframe with 1441 columns, when did a count() statement before executing save, the save also worked fine.

I am unable to figure out why its failing when I try to save directly and what changes when I add count() statement

1. Tried with lesser rows - Same error
2. Tried with lesses columns - Worked
3. Added count statement - Worked
4. Increased stack memory to 1mb - Same error

Comment: Could you please provide the complete traceback instead of just the single line of error? It will give us a more comprehensive view of the problem and help identify the root cause more effectively.

Comment: Have you tried repartitioning the dataframe?